# Converting an object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried by using `Object.keys()` to convert the object

```
var obj1={
    "jan": {
        "COAL": "25"
    },
    "feb": {
        "ROM": "50",
        "WASTE": "55"
    },
    "april": {
        "COAL": "60"
    }
}
```

to

```
var obj2=[
    {
        "month": "jan",
        "product": "COAL",
        "quantity": "25"
    },
    {
        "month": "feb",
        "product": "ROM",
        "quantity": "50"
    },
    {
        "month": "feb",
        "product": "WASTE",
        "quantity": "55"
    },
    {
        "month": "april",
        "product": "COAL",
        "quantity": "60"
    }
]
```

but failed in the middle as I'm not able to calculate the properties say for example in "feb" there are two products "ROM" and "WASTE", but this can go upto 3 or 4. Can anyone please suggest possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Is to and from mixed somehow?

Comment: The correlation here makes no sense. How are we supposed to know what's going on here based on the before, after?

Comment: I recommend you to use JS utility such as Underscore/Lodash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
var res = []
for(i in obj1){
 var rowObj = obj1[i];
 for(j in rowObj){
     var newObj = {'month' : i, 'product' : j, 'quantity' : rowObj[j]}
     res.push(newObj);
 }
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: ..Pls find this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817532/converting-an-array-object-to-another-object-part-2-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the keys in the outer object, then the keys in the inner objects, so as long as you can depend on ES5 Array methods:

```js
var obj1={
    "jan": {
        "COAL": "25"
    },
    "feb": {
        "ROM": "50",
        "WASTE": "55"
    },
    "april": {
        "COAL": "60"
    }
}

var o = Object.keys(obj1).reduce(function(acc, month, i) {
  Object.keys(obj1[month]).forEach(function(product) {
    acc.push({'month':month, 'product':product, 'quantity':obj1[month][product]})
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

document.write(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Using ES6 arrow functions it becomes a little more concise:

```
var o = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc, m) => {
  Object.keys(obj1[m]).forEach(p => acc.push({'month':m, 'product':p, 'quantity':obj1[m][p]}));
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Pls find this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817532/converting-an-array-object-to-another-object-part-2-in-javascript