# Converting an array object to another object-Part 2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a follow up question of [Converting an object into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784004/converting-an-object-to-an-array?noredirect=1#comment53406918_32784004)
.Now I would like to do a reverse engineering where I want to convert back the JOSN to the original format except its a object ,like as shown in the example below.

```
  var data1=[
    {
        "name": "Coal",
        "value": "2",
        "time": "2015-11-31 00:00:00",
         "level":"10"
    },
    {
        "name": "Shale",
        "value": "4",
        "time": "2015-10-31 00:00:00",
       "level":"20"
    }

]
```

to

```
 var data2=
    {
        "Coal": {
            "September 2015": "2",
             "level":"10"
        },
        "Shale": {
            "October 2015": "4",
            "level":"20"

        }
    }
```

where the result is an object not an array.Can anyone pls help me on this issue

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: Very roughly: `for (..) data2[value['name']][value['time']] = value['value']` – take it and run with it. Run, forgottofly, run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function yymmddToString(yymmdd) {
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April' .....];
    var x = yymmdd.split('-');
    return months[parseInt(x[1], 10)] + ' ' + x[0];
}
var result = data1.reduce(function(result, datum) {
    var x = result[datum.name] = result[datum.name] || {};
    x[yymmddToString(datum.time)] = datum.value;
    return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: @Joromanda X I'm getting months is not a function if I give all the months

Comment: Yeah. I "made" a typo

Comment: Please check the function with this JSON, var data1=var data1=[
    {
       
        "name": "Shale",
        "value": "2",
        "time": "2015-10-31 00:00:00"
         
    },
    {
         
        "name": "Shale",
        "value": "2",
        "time": "2015-09-30 00:00:00"
      
    },
    {
        
        "name": "Coal",
        "value": "2",
        "time": "2015-08-31 00:00:00"
         
    }
]  I'm getting only November's data,the rest of the dates are getting undefined

Comment: yeah, you need to parseInt(..., 10) the month, because javascript .. answer edited (wonder if you even tried to debug it yourself?)

Comment: @Joramanda, I have modified my JSON and added a property called "level".How can I bring up the change in the resultant JSON?

Comment: `x.level = datum.level`